# AuthToken in Django Rest FrameWork: non_field_errors

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, auth-token

I m trying to integrate token based authentication in DRF(Django version 1.10) but when I hit api-token-auth/ using `{"username":"test","password":"123456789"}` as mentioned in the doc it is required to return me the Token but I m getting

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

I have used `rest_framework.authtoken` in my installed apps also token is getting generated once the user is registered and save in `authtoken_token` table .

Also in my urls.py of root I m using

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', authviews.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also attaching the code

```html
urls.py

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', authviews.obtain_auth_token),
]

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'users'
]

users/urls.py


from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views as user_views
from django.conf.urls import url ,include


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', user_views.UserViewSet,base_name="user")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: is there any user with name `test` in db?

Comment: Hi Hassan ! Yes, "test" is the username stored in my database, as described in  api-token-auth documentation(http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) , I have provided {"username":"test","password":"123456789"}  as post data from my rest client and instead of getting token with key i m getting non_field_error?

Comment: show your signup view where you are saving your user. Because this error occurs when your username or password is not correct.

Comment: class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request, pk=None):
     try:
   print "i m data",type(request.data),request.data
   serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data,context={'request':request})
   print "hell"
   if serializer.is_valid():  #serializer.error
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
     except Exception as e:
      print "final exception",e

Comment: The above code saves data successfully into the user table, I have saved the password as it is without hash .Also after saving into user table I have used some code to generate token into authtoken_token table ,which is also working fine.

Comment: The problem is that you are using password without hash. The `authenticate` function use hashed password for authenticating username and password. So it is unable to authenticate it. You should use hashed password.

Comment: Thanks Hassan for the update . I m now using                                          from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password.  in my view and also it is having my password  as password = make_password(request.data['password']) & hashed password getting  saved also. Still not getting any success with http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ same error  "Unable to log in with provided credentials."Can you please do let me know which scheme to use to hash my password and how to do it ?

Comment: Kindly share view where you are creating your user. You do not need to manuly creating hash of password. `user.set_password('password`)` will work.

Comment: Hi Hassan,
This is my code:

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request, pk=None):
     try:
  user = User.objects.create(username='test', email='test@abc.com',gender='test',full_name='test',country='country')
   user.set_password('password')
   user.save()
     except Exception as e:
      print "final exception....",e

Comment: you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably not hashing your password and saving it as it is. In your view, you should save password like this.

```
user = User.objects.create(usename='test', first_name='first_name', email='test@abc.com')
user.set_password('password')
user.save()
```

`user.set_password` will hash password.

Comment: this is very simple view & user.set_password password is getting saved also for  password "password" hash generated into my user table is : pbkdf2_sha256$30000$Vb...so on

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Hassan! The issue is resolved . I have used USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' & was using actual username in the post data. Also one more thing I wanted to clarify if anyone can...I m using make_password to hash my password also I can use user.set_password to hash my password in both the cases I m getting token successfully using api-token-auth. Which hashing algorithm or library does DRF authtoken actually using then? or we can hash using any library available Django will automatically decode it ?